# Spring data save updates ID to null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am simply trying to perform an update of an entity. However hibernate attempts 2 SQL statements, one to perform the correct update and an unwanted second to update the ID alone to null, which causes my application to fail.

I am using Spring Data alongside Hibernate and when performing an update of an Entity, I see the expected update SQL is performed, however when running the application with SQL Server, a subsequent update is attempted which does the following:

```
update my_table set id=null where id=?
```

This fails obviously.

```
Cannot update identity column 'ID'.
```

Running the same code with H2 I do not see this second update triggered.

Any idea what might be the cause of this behaviour?

I am extending JpaRepository and using the default save().

Here is a snippet of my entity:

```
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String anotherValue;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private List<ChildEntity> children = new ArrayList<>();

// getters, builder, private default constructor ...
```

Snippet building my entity:

```
MyEntity.newBuilder()
                .withId(id)
                .withAnotherValue(valueUpdate)
                .build();
```

Repository:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>
```

Saving:

```
myRepository.save(myUpdatedEntity);
```

Comment: Can you add in the code of the object you are generating/updating before saving?  Also I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. You want to save an object with ID `null`?

Comment: Post your repository interface and save() calls please.

Comment: @Codeer I don't want the second subsequent update to happen.

Comment: does `MyEntity` any association ? can you update code for `BaseAuditEntity`?

Comment: I have removed the BaseAuditEntity to simiplify it as its not doing anything right now. Issue still remains. I have also added the only association with another entity.

Comment: @Codeer, id is a Long in my builder and my entity there are just getters, a nested Builder and private default constructor.

Comment: can You try using .AUTO instead of .IDENTITY?

Comment: thanks for updating the code. can you also add code for `ChildEntity`. I suspect something wrong with association.

Answer (score 0):

As i think of probable cause for this is if you associate two entities with their IDs as foreign keys then hibernate may try to update ID of parent as foreign key of other entity. Its not correct way to associate.

In a one-to-many relation add a foreign key in the many side entity, that have to reference the primary key of the one side entity class.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    ..

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "MYENTITY_ID")
    private List<ChildEntity> children = new ArrayList<>();

}
```